# What is the simplest way to use WEKA through C++ code?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, data-mining, classification, weka

Weka is a standard, widely using data mining suite mainly used in Java.  I was wondering if it's possible to use with C++, and how?

Comment: What algos are you interested in specifically, if you lest a few perhaps we can suggest other C++ libraries that can scratch your itch as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Weka by other programming language than Java, I think the best way is from the command line. [A guide](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Primer). Use your language(C++) to generate the input arff and parse the result at end.

Comment: That's not entirely true. It's quite possible to access Weka with languages that can run on the JVM. I've used JRuby with Weka extensively, and I know others who've used Jython.

Comment: @michaeltwofish yes right, for those JVM supported languages can do this.